# ProcessException: Process "C:\..\myapp\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

Tags: dart, flutter

```
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Courses\flutter\myapp\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\User\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.10.2-all\9fahxiiecdb76a5g3aw9oi8rv\gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  Command: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Courses\flutter\myapp\android\gradlew.bat -v
```

When i run my flutter app from vs code it shows this error, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the steps that I followed to solve the problem.

1. run `flutter run` on the command prompt given by your OS(not by the vs code shell).
2. make sure you have a good internet connection.

Comment: Please note that this command should be run from the flutter project's root directory

Answer (score 6):

For me, the problem was that my internet connection could not download the Gradle binaries while initializing Gradle. I suspect it's because I'm behind a proxy.

Try downloading it and installing it manually.

1. Download the [latest Gradle version](https://gradle.org/releases).
2. Extract the ZIP file to a location on your PC, i.e C:\Gradle
3. add the environment variable `GRADLE_HOME` to point to this location.
4. add `GRADLE_HOME/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with your gradle installation, for linux users:

1. Navigate to `.gradle` folder in your Home directory
2. Open `wrapper/dists` and you'd find all your gradle installation
3. If you find just one delete it and re-run your dart code from vs-code
4. Ensure you have a good internet as the process would try to download a new gradle.
5. In case you have more than one gradle installed go back to vs-code and take note of what version of gradle it is complaining about.
6. Delete that version and re-run your dart code (don't forget to get a good internet).

Answer (score 2):

This might help if you have license problem.

1. run `flutter doctor` on command prompt. If you get this:
     **! Some Android licenses not accepted.**
2. run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accept all the licenses.
3. now run `flutter run` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `.gradle` the folder in `C:\Users***.gradle` in Windows or `/Users/xxxx/.gradle` in Mac , connect to the internet, rebuild project to download the latest Gradle.

Comment: this, i think, will do what @OladapoAjala answer's does.... say his answer saves som time to build unnecessarily deleted files by deleting the whole directory

Answer (score 1):

Open gradlew.bat file in edit mode in the new window of android studio and resolve the gradle issue.
I Just delete gradle-4.10.2-all and rebuild my project.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this error with delete flutter sdk and download it again. Be sure that you have good internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
    defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
        (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.match_hire"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
```

add multiDexEnabled true might work

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by setup android project in android studio and android studio shows me error that your kotlin version is not compatible so i upgrade kotlin version.

```
ext.kotlin_version:   '1.2.71' ->  '1.3.50'
```

It started working fine.