# Flutter : App Build Failed, ProcessException - gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

Tags: batch-file, flutter, classnotfoundexception, gradlew, processexception

I have upgraded flutter to Flutter version 1.2.1. After upgrading when I try to build my application, the following error occurs. Cannot find a solution to this yet. Awaiting ur help.

```
Finished with error: ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\febin\AndroidStudioProjects\my_flutter_lab\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:28)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)


Command: C:\Users\febin\AndroidStudioProjects\my_flutter_lab\android\gradlew.bat -v
```

**Edit**
**gradle.bat file**

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ##########################################################################
@rem
@rem  Gradle startup script for Windows
@rem
@rem ##########################################################################

@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%

@rem Find java.exe
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windowz variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args
if "%@eval[2+2]" == "4" goto 4NT_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*
goto execute

:4NT_args
@rem Get arguments from the 4NT Shell from JP Software
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%$

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar

@rem Execute Gradle
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %GRADLE_OPTS% "-Dorg.gradle.appname=%APP_BASE_NAME%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

This is the gradle.bat file in my project. In the error message displayed, it is this gradle.bat file which is said to be exited abnormally.

Comment: [related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300358/processexception-process-c-myapp-android-gradlew-bat-exited-abnormally) maybe?

Comment: Already tried those. But nothing worked.

Comment: Can you post the code for your batch file?

Comment: Added the batch file in the Edit section @ZachPedigo

Answer (score 0):

After configuring signing in Gradle I got the following error messages:
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/Users/.../android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
Command: /Users/.../android/gradlew app:properties
Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

I checked it many times, but could not find out what is wrong.

I then made a new project in Android Studio and copied my old files from lib and assets etc. to the new project. It ran fine, and then I configured signing in Gradle, and the project then ran successfully. So this approach solved the previous Gradle conflicts!!

Comment: dang, I dont to follow this yet