# Flutter app gradle build exception failure

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter

I'm trying to run the sample app of Flutter in my emulator. However when I try to run (through Android Studio or through the command line) I get the following exception:

```
Finished with error: ProcessException: Process 
"C:\android_projects\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:34)
at 
org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:25)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Command: C:\android_projects\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat -v
```

When I run flutter doctor everything is fine and I also accepted all licenses.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54176889/7924072

Comment: Thank you but none of the answers solved my problem. I found it out by myself and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Was able to resolve the problem by changing the gradle distribution url in 
`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` from `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip` to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` ...

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from @bnxm answer, I changed mine from

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.x-all.zip to https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.x-all.zip
```

Basically, the idea is to downgrade it by some minor version number, just in case gradle latest release has gone past major version 6.xx.yy when you check this answer.